# pythonファイルの実行の自動化

Tags: python, python3, macos, csv

pythonでcsvファイルを読み込んで処理するプログラムを作成したので、MacOSで自動で実行できるようにしたいです。
毎回違うcsvファイルを読み込んで実行できるようにしたいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか。

Comment: これあたりでしょうか。[Pythonの実行を簡略化](https://teratail.com/questions/109801)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

たとえば Python を実行するときの引数にファイルパスを指定できるようにして、内部でそのファイルを開くようにします。

```sh
$ python sample.py test.csv
```

引数を扱う方法はいくつかありますが、ファイルパスを扱う程度であれば [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) を使えば良いでしょう。

```py
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("エラー: ファイルパスを指定してください")
    sys.exit(1)

# sys.argv[1] に第1引数が格納されているので、よしなに使えます。
print(sys.argv[1])
```

オプション引数など、より複雑に処理したくなってくると、[argparse](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/argparse.html) などのライブラリを使うのが便利です。